# mod_rewrite broken in firefox only

Tags: apache, firefox, mod-rewrite

I am having a problem with a rewrite that **is working in other browsers but not firefox**

The Problem is i have to use quotes in the url, i have no alternative due to a clients bad software submitting data to my script.

I encode the quotes in urls using %27 (i have added security in php).

```
# example.eu/horses/r/rollin-%27n-tumblin/
RewriteRule ^horses/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=viewHorse&letter=$1&horseName=$2 [L]
```

This is working (tested on mac & windows 7) in Safari and Chrome but firefox shows "The page isn't redirecting properly"

p.s It is not a cache issue

I am beginner at rewriting so im hoping the solution is simple but i couldnt work out why this rule worked in other browsers but not firefox

here is .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
#Commented these out just to see if causing issues
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.html http://www.example.eu/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^home.html http://www.example.eu/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^Home.html http://www.example.eu/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^message-board/$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.eu/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)/$ /style.css
RewriteRule ^checkout/failed/$ index.php?page=checkoutFailed [L]
RewriteRule ^checkout/complete/$ index.php?page=checkoutComplete [L]
RewriteRule ^advertise/$ index.php?page=advertise [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/$ index.php?page=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^sales/$ index.php?page=sales [L]
RewriteRule ^news/$ index.php?page=news [L]
RewriteRule ^publications/$ index.php?page=publications [L]
RewriteRule ^generateSitemap/$ index.php?page=generateSitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^fixtures/(.*)/$ index.php?page=view-fixtures&country=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fixtures/$ index.php?page=fixtures [L]
RewriteRule ^results/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=view-result&country=$1&date=$2&UniRef=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^results/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=cresults&country=$1&date=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^results/(.*)/$ index.php?page=results&country=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^results/$ index.php?page=results [L]
RewriteRule ^horses/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=viewHorse&letter=$1&horseName=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^horses/(.*)/$ index.php?page=horsesByLetter&letter=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^horses/$ index.php?page=horsesByLetter [L]
RewriteRule ^search.php index.php?page=search&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^404/$ index.php?page=404 [L]
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2992000"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|pdf|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
```

Issue is with FF 16.0.1 on Mac OSX 10.8.2 showing error "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: I've tested your rule on my local machine and there seems to be no problem at all. Are there any other rules you use besides the one mentioned? When testing, are you sure you're adding the trailing `/`?

Comment: if i comment out this rule then firefox loads the page im pretty sure this one is causing the issue. Yeah i use about 20 other basic rewrites and one that checks for trailing slash. thank you.

Comment: As I said, there's nothing wrong with your rule. The error must be found in one of the earlier rules. Mind posting the others?

Comment: updated question with .htaccess

Comment: Ok, I will have a look, but it will take me some time. Check back in the evening.

Comment: Nope, no error for me. I've tested your rules on my server and firefox does not complain. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: many thanks for trying! what version of FF and what platform are you on.

Comment: What error message is Firefox showing *exactly*? There's likely to be more text than what you are quoting.

Comment: Sorry, its a looping error, "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: @DaveJohnson FF 16.0.1 tested under Win7 and LMDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had a canonical 301 script in php that had an issue with url encoding.

I guess firefox encodes the url inside $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] differently to other browsers but...

Changing ....

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

in php canonical script to ...

```
urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

made it match the ' in url correctly. :)